# Dropbox and OneDrive

Tags: dropbox, onedrive, upload

I use Windows 8.1 and recently created a short video presentation (mp4 file) which is 1.3Gb. Just tried to upload to DropBox which was taking HOURS, then tried to upload to OneDrive with no success either. It was taking so long that I have given up. Is there an individual file size upload limit?

Comment: Why don't you try syncing it to Dropbox or OneDrive from your computer using their [respective](http://dropbox.com/download) [clients](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/)?

Comment: Your are likely being impatient along with an upload speed that is slow. OneDrive upload status is not very helpful. DropBox is better and should tell you how fast it is uploading and how long it will take.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, OneDrive has a 10 GB file size limit (2 GB previously): https://blog.onedrive.com/onedrive-now-supports-10-gb-files/?linkId=9576237

Dropbox does not have a file size limit when using the desktop clients: https://www.dropbox.com/help/5